# How to recursively sum and store all child values in a tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree

Given a tree, what's the easiest way to calculate the sum of all children at a given node?

Say a tree like this...[image]

The red values represent the sum of the node and its children.

Let's say the node structure look like this (an example):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.children = []
        self.weight = 100
        self.weight_plus_children = 295
```

How can I do this in an efficient, single pass (in Python)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having problems with performance? Why is your code so far not good?

Comment: postorder traversal would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just judge if a node is a leaf and add the sum to the weight, here is an example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, children):
        self.children = children
        self.weight = weight
        self.weight_plus_children = weight

    def get_all_weight(self):
        if self.children is None:
          return self.weight_plus_children
        else:
          for child in self.children:
            print "child.get_all_weight()", child.get_weigth_with_children()
            self.weight_plus_children += child.get_weigth_with_children()

        return self.weight_plus_children

    def get_weigth_with_children(self):
        return self.weight_plus_children

leaf1 = Node('C1', 58, None)
leaf2 = Node('C2', 7, None)
leaf3 = Node('C3', 10, None)
leaf4 = Node('C4', 20, None)

subroot = Node('B1', 50, [leaf1, leaf2])
subroot1 = Node('B2', 50, [leaf3, leaf4])

root = Node('A', 100, [subroot, subroot1])

print subroot.get_all_weight()
print
print subroot1.get_all_weight()
print
print root.get_all_weight()
```

OutPut:

```
F:\so>python test-tree.py
child.get_all_weight() 58
child.get_all_weight() 7
115

child.get_all_weight() 10
child.get_all_weight() 20
80

child.get_all_weight() 115
child.get_all_weight() 80
295
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following recursive program:

```
def calculate_sum(cur):
    children_sum = 0
    for child in cur.children:
        children_sum += calculate_sum(child)
    return cur.weight + children_sum 

calculate_sum(root)  # pass in your root node
```

Answer (score 0):

A function that adds its weight to the weights of its children, where the weights of its children are defined in terms of the function itself. Call it on the root node, and it should return the sum for the whole tree.

```
def treesum(node):
    return node.weight + sum(treesum(child) for child in node.children)
```